# Can you make an Operating system runs top of linux kernel but closed source?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is possible to just make a modified kernel open source but not the operating system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I publish everything running on Linux under GPL?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10223/should-i-publish-everything-running-on-linux-under-gpl)

Answer (score 7):

Short answer - yes.

The kernel is it's own project, and as long as you follow the license terms, you can publish your own modified version without having to publish a whole operating system around it.